# Not able to use SQLCMD.EXE because it was not present

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I want to run a `.bat` file on my server but it is throwing an error:

> No sqlcmd.exe present in any of folder under the "C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

I tried to install ODBC 11 and SQLCMD utility but not worked

```
@ECHO OFF SET SQLCMD="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" SET PATH="folder path" SET 
SERVER="myServer" SET DB="myDB" SET LOGIN="admin" SET PASSWORD="1234" SET 
INPUT="MyQuery.sql" SET OUTPUT="OutputLog.txt" COPY %PATH%*.SQL %INPUT% 
%SQLCMD% -S %SERVER% -d %DB% -U %LOGIN% -P %PASSWORD% -i %INPUT% -o %OUTPUT%
```

> (This is my .bat file , if u can see, I am not able to find SQLCMD.exe there on the given path or any other folder under in "Microsoft SQL Server" , so how to use sqlcdm or how to run my sql query through .bat file)

Comment: What was the error when you tried to install `sqlcmd`? We can't see what you see, so help us help you.

Comment: RTM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please don't post information that that in the comments. Put it in your question by editing it.

Comment: But, from the error, this clearly means you haven't installed `sqlcmd`. You can't use a utility you haven't installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the location to sqlcmd.exe to "path" environment variable.
For Windows 10:

1. Go to: Control Panel\System and Security\System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables
2. Find "Path" under "System variables" section and click Edit
3. Click New and enter the path to location of the sqlcmd.exe file

Reboot OS and try again.